# problems setting up two websites on azure server sharing assigned azure dns

Tags: azure

I am setting up a dev environment for a little bit of testing. I have a server setup in azure and would like to have two sites running on it using the assigned DNS from azure (later on I will hook it up with my registered domain but not right now). Setting up server config is not something I am very good at.

Can I set up the two sites to use the azure dns as such?

www.fooDev.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com (site 1)

api.fooDev.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com (site 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not resolve FQDN like site1 and site2. For Azure-provided public name resolution, it only supports FQDN `namelabel.region.cloudapp.azure.com`. You could not modify Azure-provided DNS suffix and manually register your own records. But you could create a CNAME record `www` pointing to this Azure provided FQDN in your registered domain zone.

This website will look like `www.example.com` redirect to `namelabel.region.cloudapp.azure.com`

Moreover, you could use [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview) manage your DNS records so that you could directly edit your DNS records in the Azure portal.

Please leave me a message if you have other concerns.